# Windows API safe termination of thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi, winapi, thread-safety

I have Delphi application on windows XP. This application works with 100 threads. At some cases i have to terminate thread with fully drops of thread's stack.

I looking for function from WinAPI like **terminatethread** but it not safelly and:
*[Windows Server 2003 and Windows XP/2000:  The target thread's initial stack is not freed, causing a resource leak.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)*

Comment: I am looking for a function to safely take over other people's cars and have them all stop in an orderly way, without any car crashes......  Anyone? Anyone? Bueller?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There's no such function. No such function could possibly exist. Windows cannot possibly know which resources are to be tidied up by that thread, and it couldn't know how to do so. That is the responsibilty of your app.

It sounds to me like your are going about this the wrong way. You ought to be terminating the thread in a co-operative fashion without using force. Anything else is bound to lead to leaks and most likely other more serious problems.

Comment: Snx for quick replay. I have another way to solv my problem, but it a little difficult

Comment: +1, I know of a way to safely end a different (remote) process (injecting a thread that executes ExitProcess using the Process' handle), but there is no such method for safely ending a thread. There is ExitThread, but that terminates the thread calling it so would not be of any use.

Comment: The only way to safely terminate a thread is to kindly ask it to terminate itself when it's ready to do so.

Comment: @Marjan, as far as I can tell, the only difference between `ExitProcess` and `TerminateProcess` is that DLLs receive a DLL_PROCESS_DETACH notification from the former. I hardly consider that much safer. In fact, MSDN describes a case where the former can lead to deadlock when the latter doesn't. The documentation says plenty about why it wouldn't be a good idea to call `ExitProcess` from an injected thread.

Comment: @Marjan, most of the things that MSDN says happen when you call `ExitProcess` are things that *always* happen when a process ends. That includes closing file handles and setting threads' states to signaled. The reason MSDN calls them all out is to describe the *order* in which they happen.

Comment: @Rob: Darn. Pity though that they seem inconsistent in that. The TerminateProcess function description only says "initiates termination and returns immediately. This stops execution of all threads within the process and requests cancellation of all pending I/O. The terminated process cannot exit until all pending I/O has been completed or canceled." But you are right, "Note that returning from the main function of an application results in a call to ExitProcess." So TerminateProcess eventually leads to ExitProcess... Picture is getting much clearer.

Comment: @Marjan: When ExitProcess() is called, or TerminateProcess() from a thread of another process, the OS stops all process threads.  With ExitProcess(), the calling thread lives a little longer in order to perform the DLL_PROCESS_DETACH which, hopefully, does not deadlock.  In either case, it is far too late for the threads to self-terminate by checking anything.  Threads not running are set to 'Stopped' and will never be dispatched again.  Running threads are set to 'StopRequested' and have the CPU they are running on hardware-interrupted to stop them.

Comment: 'though I guess any responsible program would ensure all threads already having terminated before the main thread does'. Well, kinda depends on the program.  I try quite hard to avoid doing this - if I can get away with not terminating threads until shutdown, I will do so.  Stopping threads is a PITA and the OS is much, much better at it than I am.  This is a perfectly valid approach but does imply some design constraints, eg. no comms between two threads except via mechanisms that outlive them both.

Comment: @Martin: Thanks for the info. And yes, stopping secondary threads before the main thread is no fun, but the design constraints you mention can also be a royal PITA. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If your application threads are all written in Delphi code, then consider using OmniThreadLibrary, and using its provided services, instead of raw Win32 APIs, or TThread's built in functionality, which is pretty decent in recent versions of Delphi.

However, for signalling threads and shutting them down, especially where not all the threads are created and managed by Delphi THread objects, a great deal of design will have to be done by you, and you will probably have to combine a few Win32 primitives together to build a decent solution. I would use a Win32 event and signal threads written in C/C++ using the Win32 event handle, for example.

For a pure 100% delphi codebase, I would simply use whatever is well tested, and use the TThread APIs or OmniThreadLibrary, rather than going to the raw Win32 API.