# Kill a thread without MyThread.Terminate

Tags: multithreading, delphi

In a form I have a button, "Abort". On it I have added `mythread.terminate` for killing a thread. Now in the execute method I use a variable, `terminated`, and manage it. But when I haven't a cycle, but a single instruction that take much time, as I can kill the thread?

For example, the code is:

```
procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
    Sleep (10000);
end;
```

and I want kill the thread before it finishes work, as I do? Using:

```
MyThread.Terminate
```

the a pplication freeze.

### Update:

Using `while not terminate`, can to be valid this solution, in sense it work:

```
flag := false;
while not terminated do
begin
    if not flag then
    begin
        xxx := myfunction ();
        flag := true;
        terminate;
    end;
end
```

### Solved:

I have tried to do so, and I just have the impression that it works fine:

```
procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    while not Terminated do
    begin
        Sleep (10000); // Just an example for take long time.
        Terminate; // This will set Terminated to True, so it won't iterate next time.
    end;
end;
```

What should I do?

Comment: what is the sense to create the thread that just sleeps for some time and then terminates?

Comment: @heximal: I am confident that the `Sleep(10000)` is only a 'placeholder' for some *useful* function that takes long to return.

Comment: Hello, not understood sorry :( about sleep(10000) is only a example; becouse i have saw that problem is same too in this case. Just suppose a function myfunction () that take much seconds or minutes... if i want kill thread when i press button abort from form, as i can to do? thanks again.

Comment: You can probably use the [`TerminateThread`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717(VS.85).aspx) function, but only if you are certain that it is safe to do so.

Comment: @Andreas Presumably this was offered in a comment to avoid becoming downvote bait?!

Comment: @David: Yes, but I think the function needs to be mentioned here!

Comment: @Andreas - I forgot about that. I'll add it with excuse to my answer. And of course the right answer for this question is `Never stop the threads forcibly if you don't know what the code inside the thread is doing`

Comment: @Marcello - you don't need to wait for [Terminated](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Terminated) in a cycle if you want to run you function once; it's enough to set the [FreeOnTerminate](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-FreeOnTerminate) property to True and execute your single longtime function in the [Execute](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Execute) procedure and the thread will be released after that longtime execution.

Comment: @daemon_x That's no good, what if the user closes the app whilst the thread is still running?

Comment: @David - I would say the same as if you wait in the cycle; if the longtime function is interrupted from its execution then occurs the same, end of the [Execute](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Execute), or not ?

Comment: @Marcello - you can omit `flag` because [Terminate](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Terminate) will set the [Terminated](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Terminated) to True for you so if you call it after Sleep then you will get exactly one iteration.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a single method call that takes a long time, then the best solution is to make changes inside that single method call to regularly check for termination.

Forcibly terminating a thread leads to resource leaks, deadlocks, and the mass slaughter of innocent babies. Actually, I'm not 100% certain on the veracity of that final point, but I think you can understand what I'm trying to say—don't forcibly terminate threads.

---

If you don't have access to the internals of this long running method then you really are in a bind.  I have been in that situation in the past and managed to solve the problem by corrupting the input data that was passed to the method. For example, in my case, I was passing large arrays of floating point values.  Setting all of those floating point values to signalling NaN proved sufficient to make the long running method gag and return.  Perhaps you will be able to use a similar method.

Comment: +1; for making changes in the longtime method; and hey, you forgot the mass slaughter of innocent ponies at force thread termination :)

Comment: hello, this is a good idea, but i can't to do it, becouse i havent access to this function directly; maybe the best solution is remove the button abort from form and force so user to wait that thread is terminated, you think that is valid as solution? In mine case specific user in awfull situation can wait until to 30-40 secs.

Comment: If you forcibly terminate it, it may work 999 times out of a thousand, but it could deadlock your app the other time.

Answer (score 1):

Me, I have my code like this:

```
While not Terminated do
begin
   // do some work
   Sleep(100);
end;
```

The outcome of this is that the delay before termination is much smaller. Obviously if there isn't work, it can just keep checking for new work, and keep sleeping.

Answer (score 1):

In case you have no cycle and have more than one method to be executed you can simply test the [Terminated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Terminated) property.

```
procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
  FirstFunction;
  if not Terminated then
    SecondFunction;
  if not Terminated then
    ThirdFunction;
end;
```

But if you have only one method which takes much time (for example some connection function), there's no clean way to halt it. There is very dirty way how to stop the thread execution immediately; namely [Suspend](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/Classes.TThread.Suspend), but avoid to using it because it's deprecated in new versions of Delphi and it's intended to be used by debugger. There is also the [TerminateThread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686717%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which is more suitable to cause a thread to exit.
But if you don't know what's happening in your long time running method don't use them at all !!! 
Consider that you might freeze some system resources or cause a deadlock using them.

Comment: i have tried using this solution but nothing. My situation is second case; i don't call system resources so it not is a problem.

Comment: It's not all about resources. You should also take care about deadlocks which can be caused for instance by taking ownership of some object by calling [EnterCriticalSection](http://tinyurl.com/EnterCriticalSection). Once you lock some object this way and then [suspend](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Suspend) the thread before [leaving](http://tinyurl.com/LeaveCriticalSection) the critical section you won't be able to access this object until you [resume](http://tinyurl.com/TThread-Resume) the thread.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `sleep(10000)` with `WaitForSingleObject(someEvent, 10000)` if you want to wait some time before executing and assign a variable terminated to each cycle. When calling terminate, turn on event, and let all your stack to finish normally without execution of new methods.

Comment: Hello, about sleep (10000) was only a example.  In general question is:  if i have a function for example:   myfunc ()   that when is started take much second or some minutes, (es: for much calc) and i want kill thread, before that finish it pressing abort button from form... as i do?  when i have a cycle with much i can use variable terminate for check it and i solve so, but when i have only a instruction that take much time and i want stop it...

Comment: All fat functions consist of simple functions. you have to modify your myFunc() to check Terminated at each step. If you can't do that, for example becouse of using dll or something else - there is no safety method. You can run terminateThread from WinApi but it will be memory leak.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452486/windows-api-safe-termination-of-thread - same problem

Comment: @downvoter How would that help? SleepEx only seems to wake up early if you are using completion ports or APCs... They are not mentioned here. I'm interested to know...

Answer (score 0):

> Using `MyThread.Terminate`; the application freezes.

That is only the case on termination of the application, which should not be a problem. Just hide the main form and let the thread run its run.

Of course, for an application instance running in the IDE, this works less nicely, because hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> has the same disadvantages as using `TerminateThread` for which other answers already did warn.

But during a normal application's run, there is no need to be aware of threads with a long lasting termination.